# Gmail filter to me (not on CC)

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I need to filter any mails directly addressed to me. It shouldn't pick mails in which I am in CC.

Second condition: Consider, I am in a group alias called eg:`group1@gmail.com`, if mail is addressed to `group1@gmail.com`, this should not be filtered. Filter should exclude it.

New to Gmail filters, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to filter any mails directly addressed to me. It shouldn't pick mails in which I am in cc.

This worked for me:

> to:me AND NOT cc:me

---

Update:

We have more conditions. My assumptions are as follows:

- Show all emails sent to me but not as CC.
- Show all emails sent to a group where my email is listed in CC.

Use the search string as given below:

> (to:me AND NOT cc:me) OR (to:GROUP AND cc:me)

Replace GROUP with group email.

Comment: Works for me too. Thanks a lot.

About my second condition, this is my work email and I have added in few aliases and it there a way to exclude it.

Comment: @user3093834 Updated. Please check and tell me if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: First point is correct but second is exactly opposite.

If my email is listed in any alias, mail sent to that alias should not be filtered here....

Comment: I guess this is confusion for everyone...So as the first condition is solved...I am starting a new question for the second condition..

Comment: posted here and explained elaborately - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/156083/gmail-filters-for-email-alias

Answer (score 0):

Using simply "to:me" should do the trick most of the time, but that may give some false positives, so it is better to spell out your whole email address like this "to:you@gmail.com".

Or, in case you are using Gmail with your personal email address, "to:you@example.com"

If you use your Gmail as a unified inbox with multiple email accounts, try "to:you@gmail.com OR to:you@example.com"

The way to set it up:
Enter the search term (e.g. to:you@gmail.com) in the search box above your inbox

Click the little "sliders" icon on the right. That opens a window with advanced search options.

In the bottom right of that window, you have the option to "create filter". Click that, and you'll get options for what to do with emails that meet the criteria.

But a word of warning: It is easy to set up filters that give false positives or false negatives, especially while you're still learning. For new filters that you haven't tested yet, you may want to steer clear of the high-risk or non-reversible actions (like "delete it"), and stick to low-risk actions like categorizing, starring, or marking as read.

Comment: Thanks Chris!

But when I search for (to:you@gmail.com), it also finds the mails which I am addressed not directly but addressed to a group in which I am added.

I want to read the important mails first thing in the morning, which is directly addressed to me.

Anything sent a group or an alias OR me in cc should be excluded.

Comment: It depends a bit on the group or newsletter, so there is no "right" way to exclude them, AFAIK. However, they often have elements in common that you can target for exclusion. E.g. newsletters typically have an unsubscribe link, so you could use **to:you@gmail.com NOT unsubscribe**. If the problem is only with a few groups, you can also try to target them, specifically.