# Gmail Filters for email Alias

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-search

I use gmail workspace for my work, its not @gmail.com but it's myusername@mycompany.com but we use it in google workspace, gmail, drive and all..Provided by the company..

We have lots of email aliases in our company. For eg, for all the people in my dept, we have a common email alias eg: abcdept@mycompany.com. When a mail is sent to this alias, everyone in this department receives it.

Now my question is, if a mail is sent by anyone to this alias or any alias where my mail id is included, how can I filter that separately from mails sent directly to me (to my id myusername@mycompany.com)

In other words mails sent to my id is not q question here at all but mails sent to any email alias where I am in, how do I filter that.

Is there any keyword in gmail to hold alias in the filter?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `to:alias` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like abcdept@mycompany.com is what Google calls a "group".

However, for both aliases and groups, the message should appear in your inbox with the To: field unchanged - ie. you will still see it as sent to:abcdept@mycompany.com

So, you can filter based on that To field - ie. https://cmp.onl/tbuo

If that doesn't work, perhaps your setup is actually doing some kind of forwarding - vs. a group or alias.  If you are willing to provide a screenshot or paste of the message headers, that could help someone advise you further.

**Addition:**
To filter targeting ALL messages sent to a group (vs. directly to your own address), you can start the "Doesn't have" field with to:myusername@mycompany.com - eg. https://cmp.onl/tbuO

You will want to limit to "Unread Mail" or "Inbox" as well (https://cmp.onl/tbus) - otherwise, this will pick up Sent mail, which may or may not be ideal for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks for replying Chrisputnam9  and @serverus snape

That's true, I can add that group or alias name in the **to** field and filter it.

But my company has so many groups/alias and I am in many of it. I want to filter all mails from any group which I am in. Basically to filter any mail not directly to me but to any group which I am in.

Does google have any keywords which can identify, to any alias?

Comment: Ah, I see.  In that case you can start the "Doesn't have" field with to:myusername@mycompany.com - eg. https://cmp.onl/tbuO

You will want to limit to "Unread Mail" or "Inbox" as well - otherwise, this will pick up Sent mail, which may or may not be ideal.

I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks @Chrisputnam9.

Comment: Certainly! If that did work, would you please mark the answer as accepted? Thanks @user3093834